# Reading output value via multiple render target from own framebuffer in opengl not works

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, opengl-es, framebuffer

I just want to read the RGBA 'depthColor' output later via glReadPixels() from a separat framebuffer object. Unfortunately I can only read the 'fragColor' output (GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0). What I'm doing wrong here?

.fs

```
layout(location = 0) out highp vec4 fragColor;
layout(location = 1) out highp vec4 depthColor;

void main(void)
{
    fragColor = vec4(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.0);
    depthColor = vec4(0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1.0);
}
```

.cpp

```
GLuint tex;
GLint texWidth = m_pFbo->width(), texHeight = m_pFbo->height();

m_func->glGenTextures (1, &tex);
m_func->glBindTexture (GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
m_func->glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
m_func->glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
m_func->glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
m_func->glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
m_func->glTexImage2D (GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, texWidth, texHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

GLint maxAttach = 0;
m_func->glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_COLOR_ATTACHMENTS, &maxAttach);
qDebug() << "maxAttach" << maxAttach;

GLint dfb = 0;
m_func->glGetIntegerv (GL_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING, &dfb);

GLuint fb;
m_func->glGenFramebuffers (1, &fb);
m_func->glBindFramebuffer (GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fb);

GLenum DrawBuffers[2] = {GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1};
m_func->glDrawBuffers(2, DrawBuffers);

m_func->glFramebufferTexture2D (GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex, 0);

GLenum status = m_func->glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
qDebug() << "status" << status;

m_func->glBindFramebuffer (GL_FRAMEBUFFER, dfb);

m_func->glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
m_func->glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
m_pGeom->draw(&m_shaderProgram);

m_shaderProgram.release();
m_pWindow->resetOpenGLState();
```

.cpp

```
m_func->glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1);
GLubyte z[4];
m_func->glReadPixels(xy.x(), hght - xy.y(), 1, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, z);
```

Comment: I ment m_func->glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0); This works. maxAttach=8, status=36053.

Comment: What happens when you try to read from attachment 1? Which values do you get? Or are you getting an error?

Comment: I get for depthColor always the wrong value: (204, 255, 81, 19), and correctly for fragColor (51, 51, 51, 255).

Comment: You are attaching the textures to framebuffer `fb` but then you render to `dfb`. From which of the two buffers are you reading?

Comment: My aim is to render the color and depth (later for opengl es 3.0) of a huge terrain model in one step, and read one step later (without rendering) the depth via glReadBuffer(). I thought GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 is the colorbuffer of the default fbo and GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1 is the colorbuffer from own fbo.

Comment: No. You can't alter the default framebuffer. Every other framebuffer can have a set of color attachment. You can't render to two framebuffers at the same time. If you bind a custom framebuffer, then it completely replaces the default one. I'm not that familiar with opengl-es, but if you can't read from the default depthbuffer, then you might have to render the scene a second time into your own framebuffer. Or you render to a custom framebuffer and then blit the color attachment 0 to the backbuffer.